# Macro comparison in C has incorrect result

Tags: c

Why output of the following code is `10` instead of the expected `20`?

```
#define A double

#if A == float
    #define X 10
#elif A == double
    #define X 20
#endif

int main() {
    return X;
}
```

Try it: https://godbolt.org/z/r8xhq5Pja

Comment: `#if A == float` means `#if 0 == 0`, which is **true**, and the expected correct result.

Comment: Replace `double` and `float` with `FOO` and `BAR` and you will get a similar result, but which will be easier to comprehend.

Comment: As for how to actually write such a macro, here's from the land of strongly discouraged use of macros: https://godbolt.org/z/Pdnsq81vP

Comment: `A == float` You can't compare type names that way.  You can't do it in real C expressions, and you can't do it in preprocessor conditional expressions, either.

Comment: If you need something to do based on types, take a look at the [`_Generic` selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) syntax.

Comment: So what are you *really* trying to do?  Anything at all? Because the example code is so far from doing anything useful that we have no way to suggest an alternative that would serve your purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am trying to simulate the C++ template mechanism in C by (1) adding macro definitions that assign values to variables, and (2) including the C template file that is filled with `#if` statements to select the right implementation.

Comment: __Generic selection (suggested by @EugeneSh.) may be a good solution but I am seeking something that would work with C standards before C11.

Comment: @Curious good luck with that. If you want "templates" in C, it's not too hard to simulate them using macros, you just have to explicitly instatiate them yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The standard says that in a preprocessor conditional, any identifier that is left over after macro expansion is done is treated as zero.  Both `float` and `double` become 0 — the result of the conditions is therefore `#define X 10` and the program returns `10` to the environment.

See (C11) [§6.10.1 Conditional Inclusion](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1), especially ¶4 (emphasis added):

> ¶4 4 Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the `defined` unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined. *After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.* The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of 6.6. For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation, all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, the types `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` defined in the header `<stdint.h>`.<sup>167)</sup> This includes interpreting character constants, which may involve converting escape sequences into execution character set members. Whether the numeric value for these character constants matches the value obtained when an identical character constant occurs in an expression (other than within a `#if` or `#elif` directive) is implementation-defined.<sup>168)</sup> Also, whether a single-character character constant may have a negative value is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how the C preprocessor works.

First your code boils down to this, because of `#define A double`:

```
#if double == float
    #define X 10
#elif double == double
    #define X 20
#endif
...
```

Neither of the preprocessor symbols `double` or `float` has been `#define`d. Therefore both preprocessor symbols `double` and `float` are implicitly `0` and therefore `#if double == float` is equivalent to `#if 0 == 0` which is, of course, true.

At the preprocessor level, `double` and `float` are not C keywords but just preprocessor tokens.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have described, the C preprocessor does not provide for comparing (preprocessor) token text.  In a conditional directive, the condition is first expanded.  Then, any remaining preprocessing tokens of type "identifier" are replaced by 0.  If this results in a sequence of tokens that can be interpreted as an expression, then it is necessarily a constant expression.  Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

You said in comments that your objective is to simulate C++ templates.  I would be inclined to suggest writing in *bona fide* C++ if you want templates. Nevertheless, there are ways to approach the problem in C, depending on just what aspects of templates you want to simulate.  The two preprocessor features most applicable to the task would probably be token pasting and function-like macros.

**Taking the token-pasting first**, here's a way to achieve the behavior you seem to have wanted your example code to manifest:

```
#define A double

#define floatval 10
#define doubleval 20

#define JOIN_HELPER(x, y) x ## y
#define JOIN(x, y) JOIN_HELPER(x, y) 
#define X JOIN(A, val)

int main() {
    return X;
}
```

Depending on the definition of `A` as either `float` or `double`, that `JOIN(A, val)` invocation expands to either `floatval` or `doubleval`, which in turn expands to either 10 or 20.  You can use similar to generate C identifiers, not just macro names. For example, you could generate function names that incorporate the expansion of macro `A`.

But **function-like macros** seem a likely headliner here.  Consider this:

```
#define SUM_FUNC(type)                 \
type JOIN(sum, type)(type x, type y) { \
    return x + y;                      \
}
```

For any arithmetic type, `type`, that macro will expand to a function `sumtype`, accepting two arguments of type `type` and returning their sum as a `type`.